# Sorting a large list of test scores

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting, arrays, lists

You have a large list (say N > 10000) of test scores which you would like to sort. The test scores are between 1 and 100. What is quickest way to sort the list?

First thought. We have a O(N log N) bound, but we also have additional information about the quantities in the array, so I think we could do better.

Second thought: should we use hash tables, do we care about duplicates? Cant see how to use hash tables.

Third thought: does this have something to do with radix sorting? no idea.

Fourth thought: Could we sort this list by creating another list, and then pass through the original counting frequencies of elements occured. But would we need another pass to create a larger sorted list, which would be O(N^2). ie too large.

Is this a very easy question or a very hard question?

Comment: 100 element integer array can be used as counters of individual scores? no need for hashmap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very easy question, assuming all scores are integers.

Here is the simplest algorithm in plain words. We will initiate `count`, an integer array of 100 zeros. For each score `s`, we will add 1 to `count[s]`. To produce the wanted sorted scores, we will output `count[1]` 1s, `count[2]` 2s, ..., and finally `count[100]` 100s.

This kind of sorting algorithm is called counting sort.

The case of more than $N>10000$ test scores that are between 1 and 100 is a prime usage of counting sort. The time complexity is $O(N)$ and the space complexity  is bounded by some small constant multiple of 100.

You may want to check [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm) for more information.

Comment: To fully round out this answer, you might mention that the lower bound of O(n * log n) applies to *comparison-based sorting* only, which is why this algorithm can be better than that: it doesn't use comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using sorting algorithms like merge sort we can achieve this by O(N*logN) we can do better here.
The additional information given regarding the bound of test scores is very useful here.

**do we care about duplicates ?**

if we are dealing with just scores and doesn't care about the other information like student_name or subject_info and we just want the scores in sorted format the u can use this algorithm.

```
     maintain a int table[101] = {0}   - hash table with key as score
                        //all elements are initialised to 0

    array contains all scores
    for score in array
         table[score] = table[score] +1
         //above in O(N) time and O(1) space.

    sorted_list = {} // initially empty
    for (score= 0; score < 101;i++)
      for(count = 0; count < table[i]; count++)
          sorted_list.add(score)
          //the above runs in O(N) time and O(N) space.
```

Now if we care about the info if the score like student/subject which it belonged to use this below approach.
i'm assuming you will store the score and related info in a c/c++ structure or any object format.

Now maintain a hash table of size 100 (range of test scores)
          key    = score
          value  = a list of objects or instances with this score (if you are 
             sorting for a list of students then list of students with this score )

if you are familiar with c/c++ then this data structure can be implemented using array of linked lists.The hashing technique used here is **separate hashing**.

the data structure functionality is like this
DS[score] has the pointer/reference to the linked list 
using a another hash map to identify the tails of each sub-lists in DS we can insert a new element in O(1) time.

so in a single pass from i =0 to i

after inserting we can create a new list with a single pass on DS we have created.

the algorithm is like this.

let array contains all objects with their respective scores

```
    for (i = 0; i< n; i++)
      key = array[i].score
      DS[key].insert(array[i]) //the tail part can be used for O(1) insertion.

     //the above loop runs in O(N)

     sorted_list = {} // empty_list
     for(score = 1; score<=100;score++)
       for each (obj in DS[score]) 
          sorted_list.add(obj)

      //the above loop runs in O(N).

     //the N refers to the size of original list here.
```

this approach magically is  queue based radix sort of base 100. Read more about radix sort and counting sort with queue implementation.

from the question : 
"Fourth thought: Could we sort this list by creating another list, and then pass through the original counting frequencies of elements occurred. But would we need another pass to create a larger sorted list, which would be O(N^2). ie too large. "

i think you are mistaking another pass would change N to Nˆ2 . unless you are placing the 'another pass' in a loop it won't.

i hope i answered all your questions.